# Bayesian Logistic Regression: Correcting for Pre-Experiment Bias

Tags: bayesian, logistic, experiment-design, bias

In this post, I will outline a proposed procedure and ask for critical review of the approach's validity. The context is that in a business experiment, it is known that the response variable in the test group was elevated (relative to the control group), prior to the experiment's start.

The response variable is a binary outcome; over the course of the experiment, binomial variables were collected (vectors of {0,1} representing whether the response variable occurred.) The change in success rate, as predicted by the logistic regression model, is of chief interest.

The end goals are twofold: First, quantify whether treatment exposure had a meaningful effect n the response variable through use of logistic regression; and second, estimate the increase in the response variable due to treatment exposure (likely harder, potentially error prone or even impossible.)

Steps

1. Collect pre-experiment and experiment data, dividing into four quadrants: Pre-test, in-test, pre-control, and in-control (where only the in-test quadrant received treatment exposure.)
2. Create a logistic regression model, condition on two binary variables (is_exposed, is_test) as well as any other variables that could potentially explain the pre-experiment bias. Because the response variable is binary, logistic regression is appropriate. In Bayesian design, I will use Gaussian priors on Beta slopes, a sigmoid link function, and a Binomial likelihood.
3. Extract the posterior distribution of model slopes. If credible interval over beta is_exposed does not contain 0, very likely that exposure did have a credible effect on the response variable.
4. Take two data quadrants {is_exposed=True, is_test=True} and {is_exposed=False, is_test=True}. Deliver both to the logistic regression model, which will return the probability of the response variable occurring. Subtract the latter prediction from the former prediction. The value returned is the incremental probability of the response variable occurring given treatment exposure. (**Note**: In the vent that the model is conditioned on variables that might explain the pre-experiment bias, the joint distribution needs to be sampled from and the design here is non-trivial.)

I'd like feedback that this is a principled approach. I'm fairly confident that steps 1-3 are water tight; but I'd like feedback regarding validity and reliability of inference in step 4. Could a similar step 4 be executed for the control group, even though the group was never exposed to the treatment (counterfactual)? (Sounds risky.)

Comment: Did you assign the treatment by randomization? If not, accounting for confounders will be the big issue (what you sort of hint at with "as any other variables that could potentially explain the pre-experiment bias" and there's a lot of assumptions here around how these variables could be related to outcomes and could be related to treatment assignment).

Comment: Randomized on users. In this case, users are randomly assigned to test and control based on the first time they log in after experiment starts. So it's a not a trivial "pick & choose" your test/ctrl groups situation. Hence why there is interest in a reliable framework for de-confounding pre-experiment bias.

Comment: If you did that properly (e.g. random sequence of e.g. "test, ctrl, ctrl, test, test, ctrl, test, test, ctrl, test, ctrl, ctrl..." & people as they turn up get the next treatment form the list), then the literature about randomized controlled trials seems applicable. Adjusting in a logistic regression for pre-treatment-assignment covariates (esp. if known a-priori to be predictive of a positive outcome) is desirable.

Comment: From the logistic regression you can then indeed get both individualized (i.e. for individuals taking into account varying risk) or marginal (i.e. averaged across population) estimates of various treatment effects (e.g. odds ratio, log-odds-ratio, risk difference, risk ratio etc.). Two good commentaries on this: https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/adjusting-covariates-randomized-clinical-trials-drugs-and-biological-products or this https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/guidelines-for-covariate-adjustment-in-rcts/2814/2

Comment: @Björn, suppose I’m not interested in the source of the pre-experiment bias (perhaps I already know what it is), and I’d just like to isolate the effects of the treatment. In this case, conditioning on just test group and exposure (nothing else) is the way to go correct? I believe conditioning on other variables (potential explanations of the pre-experiment bias) could “steal” from the treatment’s inferred slope. Perhaps “dilute” is a better word than steal. Am I conceiving of this correctly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. In an randomized experiment you already have identification of causal effects by comparing the randomized groups and accounting for the pre-experiment state is more a matter of precision (unless you expect that the effect will differ by different pre-experiment states, or there's missingness/events that affect interpretation that need pre-experiment information to account for).